# Loop through Resultset in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to php and i am using PDO for db operations

through a query i get the result set which is printed using print_r() function

Output looks like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [selection_id] => 8947562
        [price_difference] => 1.02
        [one_miniute_price] => 4.20
        [one_min_pc] => 0.2381
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [selection_id] => 8801685
        [price_difference] => 1.00
        [one_miniute_price] => 13.50
        [one_min_pc] => 0.0741
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [selection_id] => 9464307
        [price_difference] => 1.00
        [one_miniute_price] => 11.00
        [one_min_pc] => 0.0909
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [selection_id] => 9066075
        [price_difference] => 0.99
        [one_miniute_price] => 1.99
        [one_min_pc] => 0.5025
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [selection_id] => 8726674
        [price_difference] => 0.95
        [one_miniute_price] => 10.50
        [one_min_pc] => 0.0952
    )

)
```

Now my problem is that i want to loop though this output and access the columns for each record

Any help is highly appreciated

regards

Comment: What have you tried? eg: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I tried , but there is no output, neither any error

Comment: Just foreach() the array and you will able to do this

Comment: Post your atempts  too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $result) {
    echo $result["selection_id"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your using a PDO leads to to think that your problem is that the data is tied up in an object and you need to use some "fetch" or "get" function to release them.

If, however, that is the exact result of print_r() then does this not work?

```
<?php
foreach($results as $someResult){
    echo $someResult['selection_id'] . '<br>';
    echo $someResult['price_difference'] . '<br>';
    echo $someResult['one_miniute_price'] . '<br>';
    echo $someResult['one_min_pc'] . '<br>';

    echo "<hr>";
}
?>
```

Obviously change $results to whatever the object name is.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is in your question: "foreach"

```
foreach($resultSet as $row)
{
    //do your logic with the record ($row)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Get all variable values by using for loop and write sql insert query in loop.

```
for (i=0; $i < count($arr);$i++){
    $selection_id = $arr[$i][selection_id];
    ....
    ....
    ....
}
```